# How to create Android notifications with buttons using plyer and pyjnius in Python?

Tags: python, android

I'm working on a Python application for Android, and I want to create notifications with buttons using the plyer library in combination with pyjnius. I've seen examples for Windows notifications, but I'm specifically looking for a solution on Android.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
from plyer import notification
from jnius import autoclass

# Import necessary Android classes
PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
Intent = autoclass("android.content.Intent")
PendingIntent = autoclass("android.app.PendingIntent")

# Create an Intent for button 1
button1_intent = Intent()
button1_intent.setAction("Button1Action")
button1_pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    PythonActivity.mActivity, 0, button1_intent, 0
)

# Create an Intent for button 2
button2_intent = Intent()
button2_intent.setAction("Button2Action")
button2_pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    PythonActivity.mActivity, 0, button2_intent, 0
)

# Create the notification
notification.notify(
    title="Notification with Buttons",
    message="This is an Android notification with buttons",
    app_name="My App",
    toast=False,
    callback=lambda instance, value: None,
    actions=[
        {
            "title": "Button 1",
            "callback": button1_pending_intent,
        },
        {
            "title": "Button 2",
            "callback": button2_pending_intent,
        },
    ],
)
```

However, I'm encountering an issue with the actions parameter, and I'm not sure if I'm using pyjnius correctly for this purpose. How can I create Android notifications with buttons using plyer and pyjnius in Python? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.